# Hide a UIView behind/below other UIView and show from that view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIView` named `View1` for some main options, and another view with some extra options named `View2`.

I want to hide `View2` behind `View1`. Then, when I want to show it, `View2` should come from behind `View1`. I have tried different codes online, but did not get any proper solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "view2 should come from behind view1"? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is you have 2 subviews, one that you want to animate from behind the other. I'll declare the main view to be superView, the top subview to be view1, and the animating lower view to be view2. Assume that view1 is already added.

targetFrame is a CGRect of the final destination for view2

```
[view2 setFrame:view1.frame];
[superView insertSubview:view2 belowSubview:view1];

// Call this when you want to move view2
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    [view setFrame:targetFrame];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a lot of information to go on here. The simplest solution would be to just bring `View2` to the front. `theSuperView` here is the view that holds both `View1` and `View2`

```
theSuperView.bringSubviewToFront(View2)
```

Another simple solution would be to just hide `View1`

```
View1.hidden = true
```

There are better experiences for a user though. Transitioning to the view with an animation would be much better for this type of instance.

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.transitionFromView(View1, toView: View2, duration: .3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.transition(from: View1, to: View2, duration: 0.3, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
```

There is a large amount of things you can put into the `options` parameter here, including:

```
TransitionNone
TransitionFlipFromLeft
TransitionFlipFromRight
TransitionCurlUp
TransitionCurlDown
TransitionCrossDissolve
TransitionFlipFromTop
TransitionFlipFromBottom
```